# React-Native .scrollTo with InteractionManager not working

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

I'm trying to get the initial position of the app at x:(device.width*2) since the app consist of 3 main views, yet it doesn't seem to move even with the animation delay, it start on the left view.

```
componentDidMount() {
      const offset = window.width * this.props.initialIndex;
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        this._scrollView.scrollTo({x:offset, animated: false});
      })
}
```

Comment: This should work, and InteractionManager isn't needed. What version of React Native are you using?

Comment: I'm using RN 0.35, but I added the InteractionManager because I read that scrollview has a layout animation and that I had to delay the scroll to after the animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also tried with Interaction Manager, but i don't know why it doesn't work; setting a timeout worked for me.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.scrollView.scrollTo(cordenates, animated);
}, 0);
```